# Given two integers n and k, how efficient is it to calculate this expression?

Tags: algorithm, math, combinatorics

Given two integers `n` and `k` and an array of integers `A[n]`(0 indexed), how efficiently is it possible to calculate the following expression:

[image]

I have come up with a brute force solution with a `logn` exponentiation using squaring for calculating the powers. I was wondering if the equation can be simplified further.
PS:The `C` in the expression refers to binomial exponents.

Comment: How is this a question in practical computer programming? It looks more like mathematics or computer science, but you may be able to explain it as programming. Are the `C` numbers binomial coefficients or something else? The expression is hard to read--is the second summation an exponent? What exactly is the superscript number on the second `C`? You could improve this question by including a larger, clearer graphic of the expression.

Comment: @RoryDaulton I have edited the question. Although I think there is more of a math simplification needed, there is a chance that there exists some other solution like dynamic programming. (Not storing all the binomial coefficients, I have tried that.)

Comment: how large is n and k? What about the binomial coefficients where the numerator is less than denominator?

Comment: @juvian assume all such coefficients to be `0` and `n` and `k` can be `<=5000`. Basically you can store the coefficients in `store[5001][5001]` and calculate the coefficients recursively.

Comment: The graphic is just as fuzzy as before. You could get "a larger, *clearer* graphic of the expression" buy using a *new* graphic with more resolution.

Comment: @yobro97 so it can be done in O(n*k), seems good enough for 5000

Comment: @juvian Apparently it's not as my solution exceeds time limit for larger test cases.

Comment: what is the original problem?